# getting error Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a new laptop. I am trying to setup and bring everything down from github. I downloaded the zipfile .. when I run rails s, I get the error above. I tried rake db:migrate and cannot seem to get my app to load.. what can I do to get my app working again on my new laptoP?

Comment: what do you see when you run "bundle exec rake db:migrate:status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you've defined a migration in `db/migrations` that has not yet been run against your database. You can see this by comparing the timestamp at the top of your `schema.rb` to the most recent  migration in your `db/migrations` folder, or running `rake db:migrate:status` like bkunzi suggested.

If running `rake db:migrate` doesn't fix the issue, or if running migrations from scratch causes an error, then you may need to load your database from the `schema.rb` which should be an up-to-date definition of your database structure. To do this, run `rake db:schema:load`. If you're starting your database from scratch you can run `rake db:setup` which will create the database and load the schema.

If that still doesn't work, then you can use `rake db:reset` to drop the database and recreate it from scratch via `rake db:setup`. Be careful doing this however, as it is destructive and will permanently delete the database for that environment.

Comment: thanks a lot... i ran through these steps but am getting this message Art West@ARTWESTIV ~/desktop/yahozzle/yahozzle-master
$ rake db:setup
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

Comment: I figured it out had to run bundle update then these steps worked thanks